# cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class stepDefinitions when add cookies when init browser

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Good day everyone. 
Write tests on cucmber+java

Everything worked fine until I decided to register specific cookies along with the initialization of the browser.

What happens:

What it looks like now:

```
private static final Cookie COOKIE = new Cookie("cookie", "ANID=AHWqTUlyIThXzCDuQ8RXntFTNhBAXHx-jeqdHC12Naifw_ipukQpb2HnCyDmygAL; NID=186=CitEjYKOejCXlFxhDTRnlRbkSRPl3UP0qHNJPo56I4P1z8dsqYhFUSMNLeR1Tm8D3zyAPhHxTANbPj0ru8OVzRN15YNmCLPqyap9VoUeShDD6B8I3dj2wgnGaCmVWaJjOrXtn6BiRLxiLbb0j5wsD-U2QBxRL6mftzMO54NIAzE; 1P_JAR=2019-7-2-7", "https://www.google.com", "/recaptcha/api2/userverify?k=6LfCN1wUAAAAAGPYWdX2S6Bf3o7OOSAzATpX8X0U", new Date("2019/07/08"));

public void setup() {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", BaseProperties.driverDir );
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().addCookie(COOKIE);
}
```

So here is if driver.manage().addCookie(COOKIE); comment out then everything works as soon as this line browser is initialized and crashes with the exception of Failed to instant class stepDefinitions

stepDefinitions
Looks like this:

```
public class RegisterStepDefinitions {

private final RegisterPage registerPage = new RegisterPage();

@Given("^пользователь нахоидится на странице авторизации$")
public void onRegistrationPage() {
RegisterPage.onRegistrationPage();
registerPage.registerPageIsDisplayed();
}
```

should be noted that this class kukumber at me swore already more than once, on one of computers this error took off until brought intelij IDEA in exceptions of a firewall (I do not know that to what, but it worked), with cookies it does not pass.

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Cookies should be init when we are on page. Not before